# dynamically choose columns in select with R2DB2

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I have been trying to pass the columns I want to select in but out of the box it appears it is not possible. I have tried things like

```
@Query("SELECT :columns FROM USERS u WHERE u.LOCALE = :locale AND u.id IN (:ids)")
Flux<Users> retrieveExportData(@Param("columns") String columns,
                                       @Param("locale") String locale,
                                       @Param("ids") String[] ids);
```

and with

```
private final R2dbcEntityTemplate template;
```

I tried to create my own query and but that was not working because it has to be of type `Criteria` and that was just creating a complexity that just was not worth it.

It would be nice if I could add the columns like

```
    criteriaList.add(
        Criteria.where("LOCALE").is(locale)
    );
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.from(criteriaList);
```

and execute it like

```
    Flux<Users> users = this.template.select(User.class)
        .matching(Query.query(criteria))
        .all();
```

or just calling the repository like in my first example.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

----- update 1 -----

I tried doing like so:

import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient;

```
DatabaseClient databaseClient = DatabaseClient.create(connectionFactory);

String sql = "SELECT " + columns + "  FROM USERS u WHERE u.LOCALE=" + locale + " AND u.id IN (" + ids + ")";

return databaseClient.sql(sql)
    .fetch()
    .all().cast(User.class);
```

but Since Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE, LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap doesn't extend LinkedHashMap and HashMap, but only implements Map interface.

This results in a

```
Cannot cast org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap to User at java.base/java.lang.Class.cast
```

error.

I then tried the jooq approach suggested in the answers but it just produces syntax errors. Example

```
private final DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(connectionFactory);
private final Users users = ctx.newRecord(Users.USERS); <-- USERS not found

@Query("SELECT :columns FROM USERS u WHERE u.LOCALE = :locale AND u.id IN (:ids)")
public Flux<Users> retrieveExportData(
    List<Field<?>> columns,
    String locale,
    String[] ids
) {
    return Flux.from(ctx
        .select(columns)
        .from("USERS")
        .where(users.LOCALE.eq(locale)) <--- LOCALE not found
        .and(users.ID.in(ids)) <--- ID not found
    ).map(r -> r.into(Users.class)); <---- into not found
}
```

the library look promising. I will try to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace a bind parameter (`:columns`) by syntactic elements like this, other than actual bind values. For this type of dynamic SQL, you'll have to resort to some sort of query building mechanism.

Perhaps look at [jOOQ, which has R2DBC support](https://blog.jooq.org/reactive-sql-with-jooq-3-15-and-r2dbc/)? Your implementation would then look like this:

```java
@Query("SELECT :columns FROM USERS u WHERE u.LOCALE = :locale AND u.id IN (:ids)")
public Flux<Users> retrieveExportData(
    List<Field<?>> columns,
    String locale,
    String[] ids
) {
    return Flux.from(ctx
        .select(columns)
        .from(USERS)
        .where(USERS.LOCALE.eq(locale))
        .and(USERS.ID.in(ids))
    ).map(r -> r.into(Users.class));
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.

Comment: this looks really promising but I wish the documentation was better. Obviously a cut and paste will not work but I am really intrigued. Could you post some docs?

Comment: That's just a blog post announcing the R2DBC support. [The full documentation is here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/).

Comment: This looks really nice but adding another layer of complexity for a query requirement seems like overkill. Simply building a string with the query and injecting it doesn't feel like asking alot but it seems like it is not possible

Comment: The `@Query` annotation is for static SQL. There are many ways to write dynamic SQL, including using R2DBC directly.

Comment: I finally figure it out. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Trying your example again but the syntax is wrong.  I will post an example what I mean in an update

Comment: I was assuming you were going to use the [source code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/). See [this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/) for all the benefits of doing that, but of course you can also use jOOQ without code generation. Note: Rather than updating your question, it might be more useful for future visitors of this question if you asked new ones instead...

Answer (score 0):

you can write dynamic SQL like so.

```
import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient;

DatabaseClient databaseClient = DatabaseClient.create(connectionFactory);

String sql = "SELECT " + columns + "  FROM USERS u WHERE u.LOCALE=" + locale + " AND u.id IN (" + ids + ")";

return databaseClient.sql(sql)
    .fetch()
    .all().cast(User.class);
```

and you will need this dependency

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.6.2"
```

Comment: I really urge you to use a more sound way to create your dynamic SQL query. Apart from possible syntax errors, this is asking for SQL injection trouble! To be clear, if `columns` is a constant in your code (and never user input), that might be fine. But please don't concatenate `locale` and `ids` like that to your query. Please at least use bind variables.

Comment: ```columns```, ```locale```and ``ids``` are dynamic which is why I did it like this.. The SQL injection is a good point. I was able to get it to work but casting does not work so I am looking for another option. ```Cannot cast org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap```

Comment: If only there was an off-the-shelf solution to all of those dynamic SQL concerns :)

Comment: I Imagine jOOQ not being free, might be off putting for some @LukasEder

Comment: @YounesElOuarti: I'm not sure if I understand?

Comment: You were suggesting, that OP should used an off-the-shelf solution, which indirectly is a hint to jOOQ? If I'm not mistaken, that tool isn't free.

Comment: @YounesElOuarti: It's just one out of many options. A total cost of ownership calculation will show that it might be a cheaper one than rolling a home grown solution (that has SQLi vulnerabilities!). Anyway, jOOQ is open source and free for a lot of usages, even if I'm not sure why that should matter a priori? Probably off topic anyway, for Stack Overflow...